# saving status in sales_flat_quote_item

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added status field in `sale_flat_quote_item` table and trying to save updated status  by changing in my custom module's `Controller.php(EntitycodesaarnaController.php)` file but it not saving updated status.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the sales_flat_quote_item objetc by it's id

```
$quote_item  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($quoteitem_id);

$quote_item->setStatus('status');

$quote_item->save();
```

Hope this helps!